# Disable Parsley validation from disabled fields dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I'm validating my form using Parsley.

I've rede a lot of StackOverflow questions. but nothing works for me

The problem is that at start I have two disabled password fields and they will be enabled with a checkbox:

```js
$('#chk_change_pass').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('[name=password]')
      .prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
      $('[name=password]')
      .prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form data-parsley-validate>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk_change_pass">
    <input type="password" name="password" data-parsley-excluded="[disabled]" disabled required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.8.1/parsley.min.js"></script>
```

It's not excluded not at start neither after disabled removed

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `change`, not `ifChanged` to trigger check box change

```js
$('#chk_change_pass').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('[name=password]')
      .prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
      $('[name=password]')
      .prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form data-parsley-validate>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk_change_pass">
    <input type="password" name="password" data-parsley-excluded="[disabled]" disabled >
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.8.1/parsley.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit and you are right. I should change the event name. But this is not the problem.
I forgot to add a "required" validation to the snippet. Not as you can see the input is validated even when it's disabled!